# Get queries from multiple JSON links

Tags: jquery, json

I used `GetJSON` to get responses which are a dynamic list of JSON urls, it changes frequently.

I'm trying to get object queries from these multiple JSON urls, how is this possible ?

```js
url = "Multiple JSON links" ;
    
function getJSON(url) { 
  var resp ; 
  var xmlHttp ;
  resp = '' ;
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if(xmlHttp != null) { 
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false ); 
    xmlHttp.withCredentials = true; 
    xmlHttp.send( null ); 
    resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
  } return resp ;
} 
var results = getJSON(url) ;
var output = JSON.parse(results);
```